# Signalr connects but doesn't push a message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, signalr

I've been working on implementing signalr as part of a wcf service to talk to a .net client. Apart form a connection message all communication is one way passing a dynamic payload to the client side.

I've managed to set it up so that the client will connect to the service and pass a connection message but I can't get the pushing of a message from the service to the client.

Sorry if I've missed this answered else where but I've been unable to find a reason for this failing as it seems to follow the "how to's"

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance

Server side:

WCF external call

```
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{

    public string PushAlerts()
    {
         var payLoad = new PayLoad
                      {
                          MethodName = "alerts"
                      };


            IHubContext connectionHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PushConnection>();

            connectionHub.Clients.All.Notify(payLoad);
    }
}
```

My Hub

```
[HubName("PushHub")]
public class PushHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var connectionMessage = Context.QueryString["CONNECTION MESSAGE"];
        if (connectionMessage != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("connectionMessage");
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

ClientSide:

```
            var querystringData = new Dictionary<string, string>{};
            querystringData.Add("CONNECTION MESSAGE", "foo Connection");

            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:60479/", querystringData); //Running local till working

            hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
            hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;


            IHubProxy clientHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("PushHub");

            clientHubProxy.On("Notify", payLoad =>

                                                    SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            ResponseMethod(payLoad);
                                                                                        }, null)
                );
            await hubConnection.Start();
```

I've missed out payload but that only holds a string value at present. I've also setup a pipemodule for logging perposes.

Thanks Again

Comment: I hate to drop a link... but you may find something useful in my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185227/wcf-service-with-signalr/24185477#24185477

Comment: No a link is cool if it solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I resolved this problem in two ways firstly I moved the call to the client inside the hub its self, which I then called from a method in my wcf service.

```
[HubName("PushHub")]
public class PushHub : Hub
{

    IHubContext connectionHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PushConnection>();

public void Send(Payload payload)
{
        connectionHub.Clients.All.Notify(payLoad);

}
}
```

Secondly the client code for the method was all wrong. In the end this worked:

```
clientHubProxy.On("Notify", (payLoad) => { dostuff };
```

Took a lot of fiddling but hope my answer helps others.