# How do I get a return value from an async method before the Task is completed

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, task

I have these methods in a WCF web service.

```
public async Task<bool> DoAsyncWork()
public List<Progress> GetProgress(string progressKey)
```

If it is possible I would like to get the progressKey from the DoAsyncWork method as soon the async work has started so I can show the progress to the user. The progress is saved in a database with the progressKey as a key for the work done by DoAsyncWork.

What I understand it is not a good practice to have an out parameter in a WCF service. So

```
public async Task<bool> DoAsyncWork(out string progressKey)
```

is not a solution.

The generic bool value is not returned until the Task has completed so I can't use the generic Task class to get the progressKey.

Comment: Not my area of expertise per se but this article may help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx

Comment: Thank you @bUKaneer, but according to my understadning I can't use the Progress class over the WCF Web Service.

Comment: Would you be able to integrate signalR perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24185477/1370442

Answer (score 0):

Pass in to your task method a callback that it can call to provide you with your progress. No need for an out parameter.

```
void myMethod(IProgressCallback callback)
{
    ... do some work
    callback.NotifyProgress("Ive done some work");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure this will work over a WCF Web Service using e g basicHttpBinding.