# Implementing WebSocket on Azure Server and UWP client

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, websocket, win-universal-app

For the development I'm doing I need real time communication between server and clients.

As far as I understand, the best way is to go WebSocket. That's ok but now I'm looking for a way to implement this kind of communication on Server (hopefully an Azure WCF Web Role, at last an Azure Asp.Net MVC, but I do prefer WCF) and on client (UWP Windows10).

I'm new on this kind of technology so I'm looking for advices in best APIs to use for both server and client, documentation and samples.

Thank you for helping out
-g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best friend for this is SignalR:

http://signalr.net/

This is a library that you can basically use from anywhere. It is generally used in ASP.NET projects, but not restricted to it in any form. The following thread provides you with the answer to how you can host signalR on its own:

[WCF Service with SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185227/wcf-service-with-signalr)

Answer (score 2):

As @Pedro said, SignalR is your friend ..

In this article, you'll find an example for how to use it in Azure platform:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

And for the UWP, we do have support for that, this is the documentation and en example for that:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186447.aspx

**UPDATE:**

Here's SignalR client sample for .NET, you might need it:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Comment: Hi Nasser, I should have marked also your answer as accepted but it is no possible so I marked Pedro's one as he asked before, btw I've voted as usefull