# Socket Programming in WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am struggling with one problem, Please help me with the Socket programming in WCF services for chat application.Please provide some demo or links. Your help will appreciated. 
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR (http://signalr.net)
Simple link [WCF Service with SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185227/wcf-service-with-signalr)

Comment: Thanks for reply. It will be good if I get any link or demo of WCF service with signalR

Comment: WCF Service with SignalR, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185227/wcf-service-with-signalr