# How do i config the WCF Service Running URL as SignalR url?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, url, signalr

I am Developing a Real Time Application.I  am Created a  ASP.NET MVC  Client Application and  WCF Service.and Again i need to add the signalR concept in WCF and Client side for real time notification.

For this i am created an self hosted signalR and added this solution to WCF  Service Solution in visual  Studio.

My  WCF  Service Running URL  Address is :http://localhost:63694/Service1.svc

My  Requirement is WCF and SignalR work together.and the CLient is ASp.Net MVC4

[The WCF and ASP.NET  MVC codes are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739917/how-can-i-add-signalr-to-my-wcf-service-and-mvc-4-client-application)

SignalR code:-

```
      namespace SelfHostingSignalR
        {
           class Program
          {

                 static void Main(string[] args)
                 {
                 try
                  {
                      string url = "http://localhost:63694/Signalr";

                      using (WebApp.Start(url))
                  {
                     Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                     Console.ReadLine();
                  }
             }
              catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                   Console.ReadLine();
               }
            }
          }

          class Startup
          {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
               app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
               app.MapSignalR();

            }
         }
         public class MyHub : Hub
         {
           public void Send(string user)
           {
              Clients.All.addMessage(user);

            }
           }
      }
```

For signalr url i am hardcoded some value with wcf url address:

string url = "http://localhost:63694/Signalr";

i don't know is it correct or not.Could anyone provide me a solution to solve this?

how do  i configure the  WCF Service Running  Url to signalR url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To self-host SignalR on a WCF web service application, you just need to configure `/signalr` in `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

with MyHub defined like this:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string user)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(user);
    }
}
```

in your client MVC .NET application, you can invoke server method and define client method as below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignalR()
    {
        dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
        using(var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:63694"))
        {
            var myHub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
            myHub.On<string>("addMessage", (user) =>
            {
                model.User = user;
            });
            await hubConnection.Start();
            await myHub.Invoke("Send", "an user");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```