# How to communicate from Azure web app to WCF services hosted locally in IIS?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf

I have an ASP.NET MVC application hosted in Azure.
This application is complemented with a desktop application that also has WCF services for communicating with III party interfaces. WCF are hosted locally.

There are thousands of clients using the desktop application at different geographical locations.
Till now, every desktop application used to talk to web app using api with the help of WCF.
This was limited to on demand from the desktop application.
Whenever desktop application feels the need to talk to web app, it used the way of web api from WCF.

Now, what I want is:-
To access the different desktop applications(typically called sites), from azure depending upon the need.
This is required on account of an online ordering system that is through web app/mobile app.
I do not want to keep polling from desktop application to know about if any new order is there for this site.
I feel it would be better if I can play from other side.
Also, keeping in mind that IP of sites will not be fixed. There may be issue with firewall. NAT may translate resource identifier differently.

Can service bus in azure may be of any help, but what confuses me is that every desktop application is having its own WCF service and order should reach the respective site only.

Any type of ideas on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes Service Bus can do this.  _"[Connect your `existing on-premises systems` to cloud solutionsConnect your existing on-premises systems to cloud solutions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/)"_

Comment: Thanks MickyD, I would learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, Service Bus messaging is a perfect way to achieve this.

More information about Service Bus Messaging, we can refer to: [Service Bus queues, topics, and subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions)

In addition, We can also use `RabbitMQ` or `ZeroMQ` which is similar with Service Bus Messaging because both of them are free. You can choose an best way to realize your requirements.

About differences between ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ:

ZeroMQ has better performance, but it is built in the case of allowing message data loss to apply to high throughput / low latency applications. Unlike ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ fully implements the AMQP protocol, which is similar to mailbox services, supporting message persistence, transaction, congestion control, load balancing and so on, making RabbitMQ have a more extensive application scenario.

```
Function                    RabbitMQ                      ZeroMQ
Message persistence         Support                       Not Support
Transaction                 Support                       Not Support
performance                 Low                           High
stability                   High                          Low
Support for AMQP protocol   Support                       Not Support
Application scenario        Data loss is not allowed      High throughput
```

More information about RabbitMQ and ZeroMQ, we can refer to:

[RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

[ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)

Comment: Thanks Lee Liu for your inputs. I will surely give a try to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the desktop applications, implementing a websockets connection with [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) might be worth a look. The desktop applications sign up with a SignalR hub you provide. 
You can then push data to the clients from, for example an ASP.NET MVC app. It works very reliable and handles lots of connections well. It is typically used for realtime web communication but might be useful in your case, too.

The downside is probably, that the desktop app needs to initially sign up to a hub to receive push messages.

Comment: Thank you marcus.braun for your inputs. SIgnalR seems to be a potential resolution to this.
There is one more thing to ask following the way of SignalR.

The desktop application that I have is not having websockets. So, if I host a WCF service and implement a SignalR client inside it, I would have a persistent connection to SIgnalR hub. And whenever data is ready to be pushed to desktop application it will be sent to connected client and client would be able to process that data to database. 

Is it something worth, I should give a thought to?
I tried surfing about it, but could not get.

Comment: Moving the signalR connection to a dedicated WCF service on the client machine sounds like a good idea. Then the WCF will just be a middle man in the communication process between the hubs and the desktop app, providing the web sockets connection and doing the hub sign up in the background. Implementation of SignalR in WCF should not differ much from the implementation in any C# project. Check out this question which will probably provide additional information for an implementation (did just a quick search but looks good): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185227/wcf-service-with-signalr

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try with it. :)